# Does a surplus of low-visit content positively or negatively impact overall SEO of your site?

Tags: seo

There is a surplus of content currently on my site, and I was looking at doing a reduction in the amount of active content to make "good" things easier to find.

Would my site's overall SEO rankings for a give topic/subject/keyword be negatively impacted by removing a bunch of content that no one visits? Does this content help boost my overall SEO?